# Function not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

For some reason my javascript code is messed up.  When run through firebug, I get the error `proceedToSecond not defined`, but it is defined!

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function proceedToSecond () {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility="visible";
    }

    function reset_Form() {
        document.personalInfo.reset();
    }

    function showList() {
        alert("hey");
        if (document.getElementsById("favSports").style.visibility=="hidden") {
            document.getElementsById("favSports").style.visibility="visible");
        }
    }

    //function showList2() {
    //}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <!--various code -->
    <input type="button" onClick="proceedToSecond()" value="Proceed to second form"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 29):

The actual problem is with your

**showList** function.

There is an extra `')'` after 'visible'.

Remove that and it will work fine.

```
function showList()
{
  if (document.getElementById("favSports").style.visibility == "hidden") 
    {
       // document.getElementById("favSports").style.visibility = "visible");  
       // your code
       document.getElementById("favSports").style.visibility = "visible";
       // corrected code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things to check:

- In FireBug, see if there are any loading errors that would indicate that your script is badly formatted and the functions do not get registered.
- You can also try typing "`proceedToSecond`" into the FireBug console to see if the function gets defined
- One thing you may try is removing the space around the @type attribute to the `script` tag: it should be `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script type = "text/javascript">`

Comment: it also works with `<script type = "text/javascript">` but it just looks neater so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same problem. And found out once you have a syntax or any type of error in you javascript, the whole file don't get loaded so you cannot use any of the other functions at all.

Answer (score 1):

important: in this kind of error you should look for simple mistakes in most cases

besides syntax error, I should say once I had same problem and it was because of bad name I have chosen for function. I have never searched for the reason but I remember that I copied another function and change it to use. I add "1" after the name to changed the function name and I got this error.